# How can I extend(resolve) a Path with a Stream of String

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, reduce, java-stream

I have following two variables;

```java
final Path root;            // /a/b/c
final Stream<String> split; // 'd', 'e', 'f'

Path path;                  // /a/b/c/d/e/f
```

I want to resolve every element in `split` to the `root`.

Currently I'm trying to do like this.

```java
// is the final combiner ok?
final Path path = split.reduce(root, (p, s) -> p.resolve(s), (p1, p2) -> p1);
```

Is this the right way? Is there any other way to do this?

Is following code better than the above code?

```java
Path path = root;
split.forEach(s -> path = path.resolve(s)); // path must be final?
```

Thanks.

Comment: A follow up question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/27162090/330457

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer

```
Path root;
Stream<String> split;
Path path=split.map(Paths::get).reduce(root, Path::resolve);
```

Your combiner `(p1, p2) -> p1` is not ok as it drops the second argument instead of combining it with the first one. It won’t be used in a sequential processing, however, such a broken combiner in an application code would be a time bomb. The correct combiner would be again `Path.resolve`, however, it’s easier to use the `reduce(T, BinaryOperator)` here as in my example.

The `forEach` approach is in no way better, in case of local variables it doesn’t even work.

---

Note that it might be the case that this multi-step resolving is less efficient than constructing a single path `String` and perform one resolve operation:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
…
Path path=root.resolve(split.collect(joining(root.getFileSystem().getSeparator())));
```